# How to sort these data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I am struggling to reshape the following data, especially creating headings

```
 df<-read.table (text="name IV  IM
    AZ  No  No
    AZ  No  Yes
    AZ  No  No
    AZ  No  Yes
    KL  No  No
    KL  Yes Yes
    KL  Yes Yes
    KL  No  No
", header=TRUE)
```

I want to get the following table

```r
name    Iv1 Iv2 Iv3 Iv4 IM1 IM2 IM3 IM4
AZ      No  No  No  No  No  Yes No  Yes
KL      No  Yes Yes No  No  Yes Yes No
```

I have tried these codes, but I failed

```r
reshape(df, idvar = "name", timevar = "IV", direction = "wide")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `tidyr`'s `pivot_wider` function:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(name, names_from = "rn", names_glue = "{.value}{rn}", values_from = c("IV", "IM"))
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 9
  name  IV1   IV2   IV3   IV4   IM1   IM2   IM3   IM4  
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 AZ    No    No    No    No    No    Yes   No    Yes  
2 KL    No    Yes   Yes   No    No    Yes   Yes   No
```

- First we need to create a row number to get those indices for IV1, ..., IV4 and IM1, ..., IM4.
- Then we use the row number combined with the value's column name to create the new "wide" shape containing the original values.